# Groovy: Add prefix to each String in a List

Tags: groovy

Given is the following list:

```
List<String> list = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
```

Now I want to create one String out of this list in the following format:

```
"pre/test1 pre/test2 pre/test3"
```

So I thought I would go the following way:

```
println list.each { "pre/$it" }.join(' ')
```

However, this leads to the following output:

```
"test1 test2 test3"
```

(Note the missing prefixes.)
How can I achieve the desired string concatenation in Groovy?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
def joined = ["test1", "test2", "test3"].collect { "pre/$it" }.join(' ')
```

`each` returns unmodified collection - whereas `collect` returns collection with modified content.

Answer (score 1):

<s>For large lists (clearly not the case here) it is more efficient to form the string directly:</s>

```
def sb = ["test1", "test2", "test3"].inject(new StringBuilder()) { builder, value ->
    builder << "pre/${value} "
}
sb.setLength(sb.size() - 1) // to trim the trailing space
```

It turns out that rather the opposite is the case. Here are some test runs using 10 million elements, tracking CPU and Real time across multiple runs:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory

def threadMX = ManagementFactory.threadMXBean
assert threadMX.currentThreadCpuTimeSupported
threadMX.threadCpuTimeEnabled = true

def timeCPU = { Closure c ->
    def start = threadMX.currentThreadCpuTime
    def result = c.call()
    def end = threadMX.currentThreadCpuTime
    println "CPU time: ${(end - start)/1000000000} s"
}

def timeReal = { Closure c ->
    def start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    def result = c.call(args)
    def end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println "Elapsed time: ${(end - start)/1000} s"
    result
}

def theList = (0..<10000000). collect { it.toString() }

[CPU:timeCPU, Real:timeReal].each { label, time ->
    println "\n\n$label Time"

    print ("Mine: ".padLeft(20))
    def s2 = time {
        def sb = theList.inject(new StringBuilder()) { builder, value ->
            builder << "pre/${value} "
        }
        sb.setLength(sb.size() - 1)
        sb.toString()
    }

    print ("cfrick's: ".padLeft(20))
    def s3 = time {
        def sb = theList.inject(new StringBuilder()) { builder, value ->
            builder << "pre/" << value << " "
        }
        sb.setLength(sb.size() - 1)
        sb.toString()
    }

    print ("Opal's: ".padLeft(20))
    def s1 = time { theList.collect { "pre/${it}" }.join(" ") }

    print "Opal's w/o GString: "
    def s4 = time { theList.collect { "pre/" + it }.join(" ") }

    assert s1 == s2 && s2 == s3 && s3 == s4
}
```

And here are the results:

```
CPU Time
              Mine: CPU time: 12.8076821 s
          cfrick's: CPU time: 2.1684139 s
            Opal's: CPU time: 3.5724229 s
Opal's w/o GString: CPU time: 3.1356201 s


Real Time
              Mine: Elapsed time: 15.826 s
          cfrick's: Elapsed time: 3.587 s
            Opal's: Elapsed time: 8.906 s
Opal's w/o GString: Elapsed time: 6.296 s
```

Comment: at least it saves the intermediate list.  join uses a StringBuilder itself, so no(t much of a) gain there?

Comment: @tim_yates, I thought I had convinced myself of this at some point in the recent past, but I must be misremembering. As you can see from my updated answer, I'm basically eating my words. I think I'll leave this up as a reminder of the consequences of going off half-cocked in front of the world.

Comment: @cfrick, indeed, no gain at all if my numbers are accurate. Rather the opposite.

Comment: @BalRog once you no longer use GStrings in the loop but just call three times `append` ("pre/",value," "), it is significantly faster: 2.6 vs 0.95 / 7.8 vs 1.5 where with above code i had 2.6 vs 9.8 / 7.3 vs 11.9

Comment: @cfrick , I've incorporated your findings into my timings, and, to be fair, I tried to do Opal's without `GString` too. There is some payoff to eliminating `GString` in both cases, but it is particularly dramatic in the `StingBuilder` and `inject` case. @tim_yates , now I think I know how I got the idea that it was slower to use `collect` and `join`.